# No resource folder as expected

Tags: maven, resources

I'm trying to learn maven and work through the Maven Getting Started Guide (https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#How_do_I_add_resources_to_my_JAR). I don't get the desired folder structure with a resources folder in the main directory.

I tried all archetypes on https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html, but none of them have the desired folder struture

My POM-file:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <properties> 
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source> 
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target> 
  </properties> 
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
       </plugin>
     </plugins>
   </build>

</project>
```

Command to create the maven project:

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app
```

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ----------------------< com.mycompany.app:my-app >----------------------
[INFO] Building my-app 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\k01bagci\Desktop\maven example\my-app\src\main\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\k01bagci\Desktop\maven example\my-app\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ my-app ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.357 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-07-04T11:29:17+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Have you tried to create the folder structure yourself ?

Comment: Yes, but I dont get the META-INF directory when I compile the project again

10.    |   `-- resources
11.    |       `-- META-INF
12.    |           `-- application.properties

Comment: The META-INF directory usually is only inside the JAR file not outside..if you like to have it `src/main/resources/META-INF` ...?

Comment: Thank you for your help :)  I thought these files would be in the resources folder, which I generated manually